# finding $n$ consecutive composite Fibonacci numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

For each $n$, How can we find $n$ consecutive composite Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: Know any sufficient conditions for $F_n$ to be composite?

Comment: @ErickWong No, I don't know.

Comment: Now you do, after DenisMath's answer :).

Comment: For $F_n$ if $n$ is composite, $F_n$ is composite. Except $n = 4$ and $n = 1$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> $F_{kn}$ is divisible by $F_n$, so, apart from $F_4 = 3$, any Fibonacci prime must have a prime index.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

So you should simply take n consecutive composite indexes.